# Results of printf() and system() are in the wrong order when output is redirected to a file

Tags: c, linux, printf, child-process, io-redirection

I have a C program that compiles to an executable called myprogram. This is its main function:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  printf("this is a test message.\n");
  system("ls");

  return 0;
}
```

When I run `myprogram > output.txt` in a Linux shell and then examine output.txt, I see the output of `ls` listed above "this is a test message."

I feel like it should be the other way around. Why is this happening, and what can I do so that "this is a test message" appears at the top of output.txt?

If it matters, I'm new to both C and working in a command line.

Comment: When you mix different output and input buffers but don't bother to flush your output, there's no guarantee what order they'll get written out.  Your `printf` output could get written out before, after, or even in the middle of the `ls` output!  Granted, having output written out in the middle of other output is rare, but I've seen it happen.  Intuitively you think "There's no way one line of output could get written out in the middle of another one," but when you actually see it happen, your perception of reality is challenged.

Comment: You need to flush for printed stuff to be printed immediately.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

By default output to `stdout` is *line-buffered* when connected to a terminal. That is, the buffer is flushed when it's full or when you add a newline.

***However***, if `stdout` is not connected to a terminal, like what happens when you redirect the output from your program to a file, then `stdout` becomes *fully buffered*. That means the buffer will be flushed and actually written either when it's full or when explicitly flushed (which happens when the program exits).

This means that the output of a separate process started from your code (like what happens when you call `system`) will most likely be written first, since the buffer of that process will be flushed when that process ends, which is before your own process.

What happens when using redirection (or pipes for that matter):

1. Your `printf` call writes to the `stdout` buffer.
2. The `system` function starts a new process, which writes to its own buffer.
3. When the external process (started by your `system` call) exits, its buffer is flushed and written. Your own buffer in your own process, isn't touched.
4. Your own process ends, and your `stdout` buffer is flushed and written.

To get the output in the "correct" (or at least expected) order, call [`fflush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) before calling `system`, to explicitly flush `stdout`, or call [`setbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setbuf) before any output to disable buffering completely.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Does the program output _correctly_ even if  `fflush` is called after `system`, or the `system` does everything ( including its own `fflush` ) in that call?

Comment: Another curious question - doesn't the output of `system()` also end up in the same `stdout` buffer that `printf()` used before? After all, it didn't bypass it and write directly to console. The `stdout`s of both programs were chained - as is evident by the fact that both ended up in `output.txt`.

Comment: @Vilx-, no, `stdio` is a library, the buffers it uses exist in memory of the process. `system()` starts a new process with a separate memory space, and hence separate buffers. The child process does inherit the file descriptor from the parent, though, which is why the output goes to the same file. The difference between the OS-level file descriptors and the `write()` system call; and the C library `FILE` streams and `printf()` (etc.) is important here.

Comment: Your answer glosses over one detail that maybe the OP should be aware of:  The `stdout` _variable_ in the C program holds a pointer to a libc `FILE` object, but what is shared by the two processes is an open _file descriptor_.

Answer (score 18):

It is related to output buffering. I managed to reproduce the same behaviour. Forcing the flush did it for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  printf("this is a test message.\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  system("ls");

  return 0;
}
```

Before adding the fflush:

```
$ ./main > foo
$ cat foo
main
main.c
this is a test message.
```

and after:

```
$ ./main > foo
$ cat foo
this is a test message.
foo
main
main.c
```

Answer (score 7):

I suspect it's because of the order in which the stdout buffer gets flushed, which is not necessarily deterministic.  It's possible that the parent spawns the `ls` process and doesn't flush its own stdout until after that returns.  It may not actually flush stdout until the process exits.

Try adding `fflush (stdout)` after the printf statement and see if that forces the output to appear first.