# In c language. Why does it seem that system() is called prior to printf()?

Tags: c

Please see the code.

```c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main() {
    printf("Hello World");
    system("echo \"Hello c\"");
}
```

operation result：

```sh
Hello c
Hello World
```

Why does it seem that system() is called prior to printf()?

The above test results are running on the manjaro system, but this phenomenon does not exist on the windows system?

Comment: Probably buffering, You could try a `fflush(stdout);` call after the `printf()`.

Comment: Add `\n` to your `printf` and see if it is changing. This is because the output of `printf` is probably line-buffered and flushed when the program is terminated. And `system` is spawning a separate process at all, which is terminating before the main program.

Comment: duplicate: [Results of `printf()` and `system()` are in the wrong order when output is redirected to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52534629/995714), [`system()` executes before `printf()` even when printf come first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55301280/995714), [Why does “printf” not produce any output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39180642/995714), [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716296/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to buffering. It looks like to me that echo flushes its buffer when it exits. That output goes to STDOUT. Meanwhile your own Code has the printf output in the buffer and hasn't been flushed yet.

Adding a `\n` in the end of the printf line would let you print since printf is by default line buffered.

For more information, check out the libc section on buffering here https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Stream-Buffering.html

Answer (score 2):

Because

- you use printf to put something into output buffer
- you execute a system command with output
- you implicitly terminate the program, which flushes the output buffer to output
- the last one above getting the printed output after the system output

You only asked about why, but in case you also want to know about how to change to what you probably expect use the proposals from comments:

- Fred Larson: flush explicitly
- Eugene Sh. : flush implcitily with a newline in output

Answer (score 0):

You have your output line in the `stdout` buffer, because you have not ended it in a `'\n'`.  If you end your output line with it, you'll se the line printed before the call to system.

The reason is that `stdio` uses line buffer if the output device is a terminal.  It buffers all the characters until the buffer is full (this is difficult to see, as a full buffer can be as big as 16-32kb, it varies from system to system)  or a new line is output.  Then the buffer is flushed.  But you didn't use a `'\n'`, so the buffer is waiting until the program ends after the call to `system(3)`.

You have several ways to solve this:

- You can force the buffer flush by calling `fflush(stdout);`.  This will make `stdio` to write the buffer as it is, and you will see your line followed (without a new line) by the output of your `system()` command.
- You can tell `stdio` not to use a buffer on stdout.  This is done with `setbuf(stdout, NULL);`.  In this way, every `printf()` you make will be written as the strings are being formatted, as there's no buffer to hold them off.
- You can end your output in a `'\n'`.  You'll see how different the output is by just putting a new line before the call to `system()`.

In case your output is not to a tty device, but to a file, then the situation is worse, as then the buffer flush is done only when the buffer fills completely (not on line endings) and you'll see the full output of your `system()` call before all the output of your program (assuming you print several lines before calling `printf()` and both, the called program and the output of this one are redirected to a file)