# Python and C pipeline: Python does not write from buffer when I flush

Tags: python, c, terminal, pipeline

This is part of a university assignment but the problem I have does not relate to the assignment itself.

I have a C file that is waiting for two inputs from terminal, there are two `gets(info1)`  and later a `gets(info2)`. I have a buffered writed that I use to do the following inside python:

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write("Hello 1".encode("ascii"))
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdout.buffer.write("Hello 2".encode("ascii"))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

I then have a pipeline that sends these outputs from the python code to the input of the C program using the terminal. When I run the command I can see on the prints that both "Hello 1" and "Hello 2" is sent to `gets(info1)`. Why is this happening? Since I flush the buffer should it not send the first input to the terminal, getting catched by the C first `gets(info1)` and "Hello 2" getting catched in the second `gets(info2)`? I even introduced a sleep function after the first flush but it sleeps then sends both the outputs to the first `gets(info1)`. The pipeline obviously works since the C program is able to get the output from terminal produced by the python program. But why am I only gettings inputs to the first function even though I flush the buffer after the first string is written?

When I do

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write("Hello 1".encode("ascii"))
sys.stdout.buffer.write("\n".encode("ascii"))
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdout.buffer.write("Hello 2".encode("ascii"))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

It sends it properly. However, I need the output to be very specific

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. See [stdout buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534629/results-of-printf-and-system-are-in-the-wrong-order-when-output-is-redirecte?noredirect=1&lq=1). I needed to feed stdout a newline instead of flushing, all good! :)